# Translate a page on Chrome using bookmarklets

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, javascript, bookmarklet

### Background

On Chrome, I have a bookmarklet called `Simplified to Traditional Chinese` which translates all the simplified Chinese on the current page to traditional Chinese.

```
javascript:(
  function() {
    var s = document.getElementById("tongwenlet_tw");
    if (s != null) {
      document.body.removeChild(s);
    }
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.language = "javascript";
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://tongwen.openfoundry.org/NewTongWen/tools/bookmarklet_tw.js";
    s.id = "tongwenlet_tw";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
  }
)();
```

*Note: the **actual** code is below; I indented and added `\n` to make it more readable:*

```
javascript:(function(){var s=document.getElementById("tongwenlet_tw");if(s!=null){document.body.removeChild(s);}var s=document.createElement("script");s.language="javascript";s.type="text/javascript";s.src="http://tongwen.openfoundry.org/NewTongWen/tools/bookmarklet_tw.js";s.id="tongwenlet_tw";document.body.appendChild(s); })();
```

The code is copied from [this site](https://briian.com/6312/).

### The Problem

Whenever `http://tongwen.openfoundry.org/NewTongWen/tools/bookmarklet_tw.js` didn't work (their servers seem to crash frequently), this bookmark becomes useless.

I want to be able to translate a webpage regardless of whether `tongwen.openfoundry.org` is up.

### My Attempted Solution that Failed

I downloaded their `bookmarklet_tw.js`, saved it to a local directory:

```
/Users/ABC/Documents/bookmarklet_tw.js
```

And replaced the HTTP address in the code above with:

```
s.src = "/Users/ABC/Documents/bookmarklet_tw.js";
```

But that didn't work. Can anybody help? I'm using a **Macbook Pro** with **Chrome Version 56.0 (64 bit)**.

Thanks for your time and patience.

Comment: Any ideas, guys? I feel like there is a simple solution relating to JavaScript that I'm not grasping here.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly

```
javascript:void(location.href='http://translate.google.com/translate?u='+location.href)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/60hGo.gif

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JavaScript genius, but I changed my Google Translate bookmarklet  to use traditional Chinese instead of English:

`javascript
javascript:var t=((window.getSelection&&window.getSelection())%7C%7C(document.getSelection&&document.getSelection())%7C%7C(document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&document.selection.createRange().text));var e=(document.charset%7C%7Cdocument.characterSet);if(t!='')%7Blocation.href='http://translate.google.com/?text='+t+'&hl=zh-TW&langpair=auto%7Czh-TW&tbb=1&ie='+e;%7Delse%7Blocation.href='http://translate.google.com/translate?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&hl=zh-TW&langpair=auto%7Czh-TW&tbb=1&ie='+e;%7D;`